# How can I force a reload TCP/IP settings on Windows(XP and 2003 Server) without a reboot

Tags: tcp, settings

I am trying to optimize my TCP/IP settings such as TCP Window size, MSS and MTU.  I would like to do this with the following steps:

1. Adjust settings.
2. Force reload of TCP settings
3. Run tests and save throughputs and latencies.
4. Rinse, Lather, Repeat.

My problem is that I don't know how to do step 2.  Everything I've read says a reboot is required, but there MUST be a way to force it, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some VBScript examples to extract the data you requested (including MTU, Window Size and a whole lot more):

**All general adapter info:**

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim strComputer
Dim objWMIService
Dim propValue
Dim objItem
Dim SWBemlocator
Dim UserName
Dim Password
Dim colItems

strComputer = "."
UserName = ""
Password = ""
Set SWBemlocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set objWMIService = SWBemlocator.ConnectServer(strComputer,"root\CIMV2",UserName,Password)
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapter",,48)
For Each objItem in colItems
    WScript.Echo "AdapterType: " & objItem.AdapterType
    WScript.Echo "AdapterTypeId: " & objItem.AdapterTypeId
    WScript.Echo "AutoSense: " & objItem.AutoSense
    WScript.Echo "Availability: " & objItem.Availability
    WScript.Echo "Caption: " & objItem.Caption
    WScript.Echo "ConfigManagerErrorCode: " & objItem.ConfigManagerErrorCode
    WScript.Echo "ConfigManagerUserConfig: " & objItem.ConfigManagerUserConfig
    WScript.Echo "CreationClassName: " & objItem.CreationClassName
    WScript.Echo "Description: " & objItem.Description
    WScript.Echo "DeviceID: " & objItem.DeviceID
    WScript.Echo "ErrorCleared: " & objItem.ErrorCleared
    WScript.Echo "ErrorDescription: " & objItem.ErrorDescription
    WScript.Echo "GUID: " & objItem.GUID
    WScript.Echo "Index: " & objItem.Index
    WScript.Echo "InstallDate: " & objItem.InstallDate
    WScript.Echo "Installed: " & objItem.Installed
    WScript.Echo "InterfaceIndex: " & objItem.InterfaceIndex
    WScript.Echo "LastErrorCode: " & objItem.LastErrorCode
    WScript.Echo "MACAddress: " & objItem.MACAddress
    WScript.Echo "Manufacturer: " & objItem.Manufacturer
    WScript.Echo "MaxNumberControlled: " & objItem.MaxNumberControlled
    WScript.Echo "MaxSpeed: " & objItem.MaxSpeed
    WScript.Echo "Name: " & objItem.Name
    WScript.Echo "NetConnectionID: " & objItem.NetConnectionID
    WScript.Echo "NetConnectionStatus: " & objItem.NetConnectionStatus
    WScript.Echo "NetEnabled: " & objItem.NetEnabled
    for each propValue in objItem.NetworkAddresses
        WScript.Echo "NetworkAddresses: " & propValue
    next
    WScript.Echo "PermanentAddress: " & objItem.PermanentAddress
    WScript.Echo "PhysicalAdapter: " & objItem.PhysicalAdapter
    WScript.Echo "PNPDeviceID: " & objItem.PNPDeviceID
    for each propValue in objItem.PowerManagementCapabilities
        WScript.Echo "PowerManagementCapabilities: " & propValue
    next
    WScript.Echo "PowerManagementSupported: " & objItem.PowerManagementSupported
    WScript.Echo "ProductName: " & objItem.ProductName
    WScript.Echo "ServiceName: " & objItem.ServiceName
    WScript.Echo "Speed: " & objItem.Speed
    WScript.Echo "Status: " & objItem.Status
    WScript.Echo "StatusInfo: " & objItem.StatusInfo
    WScript.Echo "SystemCreationClassName: " & objItem.SystemCreationClassName
    WScript.Echo "SystemName: " & objItem.SystemName
    WScript.Echo "TimeOfLastReset: " & objItem.TimeOfLastReset
Next
```

**All specific adapter config:**

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim strComputer
Dim objWMIService
Dim propValue
Dim objItem
Dim SWBemlocator
Dim UserName
Dim Password
Dim colItems

strComputer = "."
UserName = ""
Password = ""
Set SWBemlocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set objWMIService = SWBemlocator.ConnectServer(strComputer,"root\CIMV2",UserName,Password)
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration",,48)
For Each objItem in colItems
    WScript.Echo "ArpAlwaysSourceRoute: " & objItem.ArpAlwaysSourceRoute
    WScript.Echo "ArpUseEtherSNAP: " & objItem.ArpUseEtherSNAP
    WScript.Echo "Caption: " & objItem.Caption
    WScript.Echo "DatabasePath: " & objItem.DatabasePath
    WScript.Echo "DeadGWDetectEnabled: " & objItem.DeadGWDetectEnabled
    for each propValue in objItem.DefaultIPGateway
        WScript.Echo "DefaultIPGateway: " & propValue
    next
    WScript.Echo "DefaultTOS: " & objItem.DefaultTOS
    WScript.Echo "DefaultTTL: " & objItem.DefaultTTL
    WScript.Echo "Description: " & objItem.Description
    WScript.Echo "DHCPEnabled: " & objItem.DHCPEnabled
    WScript.Echo "DHCPLeaseExpires: " & objItem.DHCPLeaseExpires
    WScript.Echo "DHCPLeaseObtained: " & objItem.DHCPLeaseObtained
    WScript.Echo "DHCPServer: " & objItem.DHCPServer
    WScript.Echo "DNSDomain: " & objItem.DNSDomain
    for each propValue in objItem.DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder
        WScript.Echo "DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder: " & propValue
    next
    WScript.Echo "DNSEnabledForWINSResolution: " & objItem.DNSEnabledForWINSResolution
    WScript.Echo "DNSHostName: " & objItem.DNSHostName
    for each propValue in objItem.DNSServerSearchOrder
        WScript.Echo "DNSServerSearchOrder: " & propValue
    next
    WScript.Echo "DomainDNSRegistrationEnabled: " & objItem.DomainDNSRegistrationEnabled
    WScript.Echo "ForwardBufferMemory: " & objItem.ForwardBufferMemory
    WScript.Echo "FullDNSRegistrationEnabled: " & objItem.FullDNSRegistrationEnabled
    for each propValue in objItem.GatewayCostMetric
        WScript.Echo "GatewayCostMetric: " & propValue
    next
    WScript.Echo "IGMPLevel: " & objItem.IGMPLevel
    WScript.Echo "Index: " & objItem.Index
    WScript.Echo "InterfaceIndex: " & objItem.InterfaceIndex
    for each propValue in objItem.IPAddress
        WScript.Echo "IPAddress: " & propValue
    next
    WScript.Echo "IPConnectionMetric: " & objItem.IPConnectionMetric
    WScript.Echo "IPEnabled: " & objItem.IPEnabled
    WScript.Echo "IPFilterSecurityEnabled: " & objItem.IPFilterSecurityEnabled
    WScript.Echo "IPPortSecurityEnabled: " & objItem.IPPortSecurityEnabled
    for each propValue in objItem.IPSecPermitIPProtocols
        WScript.Echo "IPSecPermitIPProtocols: " & propValue
    next
    for each propValue in objItem.IPSecPermitTCPPorts
        WScript.Echo "IPSecPermitTCPPorts: " & propValue
    next
    for each propValue in objItem.IPSecPermitUDPPorts
        WScript.Echo "IPSecPermitUDPPorts: " & propValue
    next
    for each propValue in objItem.IPSubnet
        WScript.Echo "IPSubnet: " & propValue
    next
    WScript.Echo "IPUseZeroBroadcast: " & objItem.IPUseZeroBroadcast
    WScript.Echo "IPXAddress: " & objItem.IPXAddress
    WScript.Echo "IPXEnabled: " & objItem.IPXEnabled
    for each propValue in objItem.IPXFrameType
        WScript.Echo "IPXFrameType: " & propValue
    next
    WScript.Echo "IPXMediaType: " & objItem.IPXMediaType
    for each propValue in objItem.IPXNetworkNumber
        WScript.Echo "IPXNetworkNumber: " & propValue
    next
    WScript.Echo "IPXVirtualNetNumber: " & objItem.IPXVirtualNetNumber
    WScript.Echo "KeepAliveInterval: " & objItem.KeepAliveInterval
    WScript.Echo "KeepAliveTime: " & objItem.KeepAliveTime
    WScript.Echo "MACAddress: " & objItem.MACAddress
    WScript.Echo "MTU: " & objItem.MTU
    WScript.Echo "NumForwardPackets: " & objItem.NumForwardPackets
    WScript.Echo "PMTUBHDetectEnabled: " & objItem.PMTUBHDetectEnabled
    WScript.Echo "PMTUDiscoveryEnabled: " & objItem.PMTUDiscoveryEnabled
    WScript.Echo "ServiceName: " & objItem.ServiceName
    WScript.Echo "SettingID: " & objItem.SettingID
    WScript.Echo "TcpipNetbiosOptions: " & objItem.TcpipNetbiosOptions
    WScript.Echo "TcpMaxConnectRetransmissions: " & objItem.TcpMaxConnectRetransmissions
    WScript.Echo "TcpMaxDataRetransmissions: " & objItem.TcpMaxDataRetransmissions
    WScript.Echo "TcpNumConnections: " & objItem.TcpNumConnections
    WScript.Echo "TcpUseRFC1122UrgentPointer: " & objItem.TcpUseRFC1122UrgentPointer
    WScript.Echo "TcpWindowSize: " & objItem.TcpWindowSize
    WScript.Echo "WINSEnableLMHostsLookup: " & objItem.WINSEnableLMHostsLookup
    WScript.Echo "WINSHostLookupFile: " & objItem.WINSHostLookupFile
    WScript.Echo "WINSPrimaryServer: " & objItem.WINSPrimaryServer
    WScript.Echo "WINSScopeID: " & objItem.WINSScopeID
    WScript.Echo "WINSSecondaryServer: " & objItem.WINSSecondaryServer
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can right-click on the network icon and choose **Repair**:

[Repair your network connection http://img146.imageshack.us/img146/7096/picture5okk.png](http://img146.imageshack.us/img146/7096/picture5okk.png)

A way to access it programmatically is to use the "netsh" command-line utility:

```
> netsh interface dump
```

Here's a link to a [blog which may help](http://smallvoid.com/article/vista-tcpip-mtu.html).

I tried some of the suggested commands on our Win 2003 Server, and thank you, Microsoft, they've apparently changed the command syntax.

But I'm certain if you play around with it you'll find the appropriate commands for your situation.

Comment: I should clarify that I am doing this within an application, ie these are not manual steps.  However, I can do the equivalent of the repair with dos commands.  The question is whether this actually reloads these settings.  Which allows me to pose the question slightly differently.  How can I get the current active TCP/IP settings - TCP Window, MTU, MSS, etc?

Comment: Updated to answer your question... again.